# JQuery each on associative JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, each

Hey friends can you help me out with this issue. I have a JSON:

```
video_orders = {
    "channel": {
        "1": "relevance",
        "2": "published",
        "3": "viewCount",
        "4": "rating"
    },
    "playlist": {
        "1": "position",
        "2": "commentCount",
        "3": "duration",
        "4": "published",
        "5": "title",
        "6": "viewCount"
    },
    "favorites": {
        "1": "standard"
    }
}
```

What i am trying to do is a Jquery each to get all values inside the keys like "channel", "playlist", "favorites".

Currenly what i am doing is:

```
$(video_orders['channel']).each(function(index, value){
   console.log(index+' : '+value);
})
```

So the output should be like:(if i do console.log)

```
1 : relevance
2 : published
3 : viewCount
4 : rating
```

But what i get is all wrong. What am i doing wrong? How can accomplish it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong `each`, you want [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), not [`$(...).each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$.each(video_orders['channel'], function(index, value){
   console.log(index+' : '+value);
});
```

The [`$(...).each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function is used to iterate over a set of matched DOM elements:

> Iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element.

The [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function is:

> A generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate over both objects and arrays.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Ax7Eu/

Comment: Thanks guys, my mistake. Really appreciate for the quick and perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use `$(selector).each(function)` (which is meant for jQuery selectors) instead of `$.each(collection, function)` (which is meant for any collection). http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/